# IP Telephone call to RTP Stream

Tags: voip, voice, telephony

Can anyone please tell me if it is possible to publish the voice from an IP based telephone to a RTP based media server - like a Wowza Media Server or Flash Media Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to give more info if you want a more specific answer, but a quick response is that yes it is possible.

If the IP phones is something you are building or can modify then you can simply send any outgoing RTP packets both to the other end of the call and the media server, and forward any received RTP packets to the media server.

If you are not able to modify the phone, then you may still be able to achieve what you are looking for by 'mirroring' the RTP packets that are sent to and received from the IP phone, to the RTP media server (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring for an overview of port mirroring, and www.audiocodes.com/filehandler.ashx?fileid=43289 for some specific discussion on 'tapping' phone calls).

Note, that you need to be aware of the law if this is to record or 'tap' live calls. Even if they are your own calls on your own phone, different countries have different laws about what can and cannot be recorded and what notification you have to give the parties involved in the call (this is why calls to call centers etc often start with a message that the call may be recorded for training or other purposes).